# Creating class as specified by input

Tags: python, oop

```
                new_piece = input('What would you like to promote your Pawn to? ')
                if new_piece.capitalize() not in ['Queen','Bishop','Knight','Rook']:
                    print('Please choose one of: Queen, Bishop, Knight, or Rook')
                else:
                    if chosen_piece._white:
                        name = new_piece.lower() + 'w' + str(turn)
                    else:
                        name = new_piece.lower() + 'b' + str(turn)
                    for 
                    pieces[name] = new_piece.capitalize()(name, board[chosen_piece._position._name], chosen_piece._white)
                    board[chosen_piece._position._name].square_piece = pieces[name]
```

I am trying to create a new object where the class is specified by user input.
with the above code I get:

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I could achieve the desired result by several if/ elif statements creating an object of the desired class if the input matches the class name but this would be 12 lines of code where one might work.

thanks

edit:
Here is the 'ugly' way:

```
new_piece = input('What would you like to promote your Pawn to? ')
if new_piece.capitalize() not in ['Queen','Bishop','Knight','Rook']:
    print('Please choose one of: Queen, Bishop, Knight, or Rook')
else:
    if chosen_piece._white:
        name = new_piece.lower() + 'w' + str(turn)
    else:
        name = new_piece.lower() + 'b' + str(turn)
    if new_piece.capitalize() == 'Queen':
        pieces[name] = Queen(name, board[chosen_piece._position._name], chosen_piece._white)
        board[chosen_piece._position._name].square_piece = pieces[name]
        breaker = True
        break
    elif new_piece.capitalize() == 'Bishop':
        pieces[name] = Bishop(name, board[chosen_piece._position._name], chosen_piece._white)
        board[chosen_piece._position._name].square_piece = pieces[name]
        breaker = True
        break
    elif new_piece.capitalize() == 'Knight':
        pieces[name] = Knight(name, board[chosen_piece._position._name], chosen_piece._white)
        board[chosen_piece._position._name].square_piece = pieces[name]
        breaker = True
        break
    elif new_piece.capitalize() == 'Rook':
        pieces[name] = Rook(name, board[chosen_piece._position._name], chosen_piece._white)
        board[chosen_piece._position._name].square_piece = pieces[name]
        breaker = True
        break
```

Comment: is that all the code? because there is even syntax error in the code

Comment: no it's like 400 lines so I just put the bit in that was necessary

Comment: Have you created a variable named str before? for now I can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to instantiate a class based on a name it is convenient to use a dictionary as a mapper where the name is the key and the class is the value.  Here is an intentionally simplified example to highlight the technique.

Example:

```
class Queen:
    def __init__(self):
        print("I'm a Queen!")
class King:
    def __init__(self):
        print("I'm a King!")
class Bishop:
    def __init__(self):
        print("I'm a Bishop!")

chess_class_map = {
    "Queen": Queen,
    "King": King,
    "Bishop": Bishop,
}

piece_name = input("Enter chess piece to make: ")

piece_class = chess_class_map.get(piece_name.capitalize())
if piece_class:
    piece = piece_class()
else:
    print(f"Unable to make chess piece: {piece_name}")
```